# Code executing 3 times itself without telling it to do so

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py

I am currently making a custom badge system for my discord bot, but when I executed the command, it went through 3 times. I think it depends on the JSON file, so like if the user is in the JSON file and was on the second one it will go through 2 times.

My code:

```
@client.command()
@commands.guild_only()
async def userinfo(ctx, *, user: discord.Member = None):
            if user is None:
                user = ctx.author
            try:
                data = get_data()
                embed = discord.Embed(timestamp=ctx.message.created_at, colour=discord.Color.dark_green())
                for profile in data:
                    print("Checking if user is in db")
                    if profile['discord_id'] == f"{user.id}":
                        print("User is in db")
                        badges = profile["badges"]
                        date_format = "%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M %p"
                        embed.set_author(name=f"{user}", icon_url=user.avatar_url)
                        embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
                        embed.add_field(name="Badges", value=badges, inline=True)
                        embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
                    else:
                        print("User not in db, registering user into db")
                        data = get_data()
                        data.append({"discord_id": f"{user.id}", "badges": "None."})
                        set_data(data)
                await ctx.send(embed = embed)
            except Exception as e:
                await ctx.send(f"error {e}")
```

```
def get_data():
    with open('profiles.json', 'r') as file:
        return loads(file.read())

def set_data(data):
    with open('profiles.json', 'w') as file:
        file.write(dumps(data, indent=2))

def profile(badges, discord_id, mode):
    data = get_data()
    if mode == 'create':
        data.append({"discord_id": discord_id, "badges": badges})
    elif mode == 'modify':
        for profile in data:
            if profile['discord_id'] == f"{discord_id}":
                profile = {'discord_id': f"{discord_id}", 'badges': f"{badges}"}
    set_data(data)
```

JSON file:

```
[
  {
    "discord_id": "727823455734464642",
    "badges": "<:verified:774247562299310101> <:botdev:774247435483480084>"
  },
  {
    "discord_id": "744337705940287499",
    "badges": "<:bot:774254414214725683>"
  },
  {
    "discord_id": "689415225891487774",
    "badges": "None."
  }
]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the way you've structured your loop and if-statement. Here is some code that is meant to replicate your mistake:

```
users = ["bob", "tom", "james"]

user_to_find = "tom"

for user in users:
    if user == user_to_find:
        print(f"{user_to_find} is in the list!")
    else:
        print(f"{user_to_find} is not in the list.")
```

Output:

```
tom is not in the list.
tom is in the list!
tom is not in the list.
>>>
```

Now, obviously this is wrong. We can't know that a user is not in the list until we've looked at the entire list. What we want to do is something like:

- If the current user is the user we're looking for, then we know the
  user exists in the list, and we don't need to keep looking, so we
  would `break` out of the loop at that point.
- If the current user is not the user we're looking for, we move on to
  the next user and ask the same question again.
- When the loop ends, and we've looked at all users without breaking out
  of the loop, then we can know for certain that the user we're looking
  for doesn't exist.

One possible solution:

```
for user in users:
    if user == user_to_find:
        print(f"{user_to_find} is in the list!")
        break
else:
    print(f"{user_to_find} is not in the list.")
```

Output:

```
tom is in the list!
>>>
```

Notice the for-else syntax you can take advantage of in this case. The `else` is not paired with the `if`, but rather, on the same level of indentation as the `for`. This syntax means, if we didn't `break` out of the loop, enter the body of the `else`. In other words, if none of the users in the list matched the user we were looking for, enter the body of the `else`.

There's another problem with your code, which is that you are potentially modifying `data` as you are iterating over it, which is never a good idea.

In your case, the fix would be:

```
print("Checking if user is in db")
for profile in data:        
    if profile['discord_id'] == f"{user.id}":
        print("User is in db")
        badges = profile["badges"]
        date_format = "%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M %p"
        embed.set_author(name=f"{user}", icon_url=user.avatar_url)
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=user.avatar_url)
        embed.add_field(name="Badges", value=badges, inline=True)
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Requested by {ctx.author.name}#{ctx.author.discriminator}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        break
else:
    print("User not in db, registering user into db")
    data = get_data()
    data.append({"discord_id": f"{user.id}", "badges": "None."})
    set_data(data)
```